# Restart a script after 6 minutes

Tags: python, timer

I want to make a `for` loop in Python which will restart itself after 6 minutes or until the loop has finish doing itself 500 times.

Maybe there is a command which I can apply at the start of the script to make it restart after 6 minutes.

My script is:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    # something
    sys.exit()
else:
    if sys.argv[1]=="help":
        # something
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "start"
        if len(sys.argv)== 3:
            if sys.argv[2]=="safe":
                set_safe()
        url = sys.argv[1]
        if url.count("/")==2:
            url = url + "/"
        m = re.search('http\://([^/]*)/?.*', url)
        host = m.group(1)
        for i in range(500):
            # something
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Use sleep(...) method of time module for 6 minutes time.sleep(300)

Comment: @mmachine But it will stop the loop after one round for 6 minutes and I don't want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach should work, it first calculates 6 minutes into the future and starts your "script" executing 500 times. It then simply waits in a loop until the wake up time is reached. So your script can take any amount of time. If it takes longer, then the next 500 will start immediately.

```
import time

wakeup = time.time()

while True:
    wakeup += 6 * 60

    for i in range(500):
        # something 

        # Has it taken longer the 6 minutes?
        if time.time() > wakeup:
            break

    while time.time() < wakeup:
        time.sleep(1)
```

You can change the `sleep(1)` value to whatever your want, e.g. 5. It will not effect the overall rate but will just mean the next iteration will start within 5 seconds of 6 minutes rather than 1 second of 6 minutes (if that makes sense).

Try the following demo version: The following version runs every 6 seconds (not minutes) and tries to do the `for` loop 20 times. I slow it down by 0.5 seconds each iteration to simulate work.

```
import time

wakeup = time.time()

while True:
    wakeup += 6 
    print "start",

    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.5)   # simulate work
        print i,

        if time.time() > wakeup:
            break

    print "finished"

    while time.time() < wakeup:
        time.sleep(1)
```

You will see the following output:

```
start 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 finished
start 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 finished
start 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 finished
```

As you can see, the loop is aborted when 6 seconds are up and before all 20 iterations are reached and it is then restarted.

Comment: Hmm... can I use it in the loop? Because I want to make the for loop stop if 6 minutes are passed **or** after the loop has ended and 6 minutes are gone

Comment: Yes, you would just read to test if the wakeup time has been reached and break out of the loop.

Comment: Will the `time.sleep(1)` restart my script? Because I need a script restarter. I was thinking about call a function which include the `for in in range (500):`, so instead of `time.sleep(1)` it will restart the `While` loop. Can you please edit your answer?

Comment: The `while True` loop will ensure you stay running. You do not need to restart it. `sleep(1)` puts your script to sleep for one second so it does not use any CPU.

Comment: What do you mean by restart? What is one unit of work? If you try the script you will see that it does rerun the `for` loop every 6 minutes. `while True` simply means loop forever.

Comment: I meant that I want to make the `for i in range (500)` to start from 0 again... That's what restart the `for` loop meant. I can't edit my comment, so I meant :
 
I need a `for` loop restarter. I was thinking about call a function which include the `for in in range (500):`, so instead of `time.sleep(1)` it will restart the `for` loop . Can you please edit your answer?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to restart the script after 6 minutes, is to use a `while loop` and use a `counter` to count the 500 times, mixed with a `timer` for the time delay.

```
import time

counter = 0

while counter <= 500:
    <SCRIPT>
    ........
    ........
    counter += 1
    time.sleep(6 * 60)
```

The `time.sleep()` function takes the time in seconds as a parameter, so `6 * 60` will give you 6 minutes.

Comment: `Counter += 1` you meant, there is not `++` in Python

Comment: @RonHalfon Yes! Thank you. I'm so used to writing in Java and C++ haha

Comment: Won't this sleep on each iteration of the loop? I don't think that is the desired effect.

Comment: @DrewB you are correct. It will stop the `for` loop and I don't desire it. I want to make it stop the loop after 6 minutes while it is running, and not stop the loop after one round for 6 minutes